# Split lines's strings from a txt file in 2 different arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with x and y coordinates. I am trying to store the coordinates to x and y arrays. This is the file I want to store.

```
100 511
52 502
384 94
46 506
54 508
399 101
394 93
```

I expect to be like this

```
x[0] = 100, y[0] = 511;
x[1] = 52, y[1] =502
```

and so on

```
for n in range(0,lines[0].find(' ')):
    i = 0
    x[i] = x[i] + n
    i = i + 1
```

I have tried something like this to find the 'space' but it didn't work. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
num_list = [line.strip('\n').split() for line in open('numbers.txt').readlines()]
x, y = zip(*num_list)
print x, y

Result: ('100', '52', '384', '46', '54', '399', '394') ('511', '502', '94', '506', '508', '101', '93')
```

Read number.txt and zip it.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
x, y = zip(*[i.split() for i in lines])
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw answer:

```
x = []
y = []

with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        x_coord, y_coord = line.split()
        x.append(x_coord)
        y.append(y_coord)
```